# Como fazer uma lista com os 5 maiores valores de um objeto? Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tenho um array com 15 objetos, cada um com a propriedade "varBid" do tipo number, preciso fazer um outro array com apenas as 5 maiores valores varBid.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada (e antes mesmo disso dar uma pesquisada se o assunto já foi tratado no site - grande chance de já ter postagem com a solução). Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.

Comment: Já tentou classificar o array em ordem decrescente e pegar os cinco primeiros elementos?